# create child case button not showing on case layout (lightning)

Tags: lightning, case, quickaction

I want to create a child case for a case in lightning. From the related list "Related cases", when I click on "New", the account field on the child case is not fill. 
For information, I am using person account with cases which have recordtypes.

I want to be able to default the account id in the account field of the child case. I wanted to use the standard "new child case" action, but when i added it on my page layout, it is not showing.

I read this article https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=actions_considerations.htm&type=5 about the child case button, and i am admin of the system, and have full rights on the recordtypes and the parent field, but can't display that action.

What I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that for Cases, Actions appear in the feed view, which is super frustrating.
I have been trying to achieve the same outcome but was unable to get Parent Case field to populate which is very frustrating.
Ideally, I would just use the related list "Related Cases" and then press new, but it **only** populates Parent case, which is just as frustrating, and you cannot modify these.

I have gone back to trying to create a URL button, so that it appears on Case detail next to the other buttons, but no matter what I try I still can't get Parent Case populated, so I suspect it can only be achieved using flow.

URL button:
/{!Case.Id}/e?clone=1&retURL=/{!Case.Id}&common.udd.actions.ActionsUtilORIG_URI=/{!Case.Id}/e&00N9000000EklOx={!Case.CaseNumber}

I have Engaged Salesforce a while ago, I will let you know if I get an outcome

Answer (score 0):

[Take a look](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008fpiQAA&title=case-related-list-behavior-is-not-consistent-between-salesforce-classic-and-lightning-experience-when-using-person-acounts) and see if this describes your issue and if the workaround works for you.

If not, you can get around this a few ways by either creating a custom quick action with predefined values or by creating a quick flow action that uses a visual flow that pulls these values in.